# Why 2 immutable.js Lists is deeply different?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I couldn't deeply compare 2 Lists, using simple deep object comparison.

Consider following code:

```
import {fromJS} from 'immutable';
import {describe, it} from 'mocha';
import { expect } from 'chai';

const o = {a: 123};
const A = fromJS([o]);
const B = fromJS([]).push(fromJS(o));

describe('Check', () => {
  it('should be deep equal', () => {
    expect(A).to.deep.equal(B);
  });
});
```

Why Immutable.js collections actually have state?

I saw libraries like [chai-immutable](https://github.com/astorije/chai-immutable), but I would like to understand purpose of this behavior?

Comment: I don't understand the issue here - surely these would end up as two _different_ objects with merely the _same data_ in them. I'd expect the equality to fail.

Comment: Immutable.js uses a state to make it efficient, so that when you add something to an immutable list, the references will be different but it won´t actually copy everything and be O(n)

Comment: @juvian, thank you. I could remove my question or accept your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immutable.js uses a state to make it efficient, so that when you add something to an immutable list, the references will be different but it won´t actually copy everything and be O(n).

As stated in their [Github](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/) :

> These data structures are highly efficient on modern JavaScript VMs by using structural sharing via hash maps tries and vector tries as popularized by Clojure and Scala, minimizing the need to copy or cache data.